# Typescript - generics infer and define can not work together

Tags: javascript, typescript, types

Here is generics infer(not infer keyword) demo:

```js
function foo<A>(a: A): A {}

const result = foo({ a: 1 });
//  const result: {
//    a: number;
//  }
```

But it seems i can't add some "extra" types to function foo, otherwise infer will not working:

```js
function foo<Extra, A>(a: A): A & Extra {}

const result = foo<{ b: number }>({ a: 1 });
//  const result: {
//    b: number;
//  }
```

So, what i want is the function foo can both has type a and b in the above example, can anyone help?

Comment: TS does not have partial type parameter inference as requested in [ms/TS#26242](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/26242) See the answer to the linked questions for more info and workarounds.